# Mostrar info en pagina PHP antes de redirigir/cerrar ventana

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de controlar un error, el error lo estoy forzando, por lo que ignoren eso...

Al momento de que la página detecte que no puede procesar, quiero que imprima datos, información, o algún detalle, y que luego de un tiempo, redirija o cierre dicha pestaña.

Ahora mismo estoy probando esto:

```
//[...]
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    //Todo ok, se obtuvieron datos
}else{
    echo "Se cerrará esta ventana"; // Mensaje a mostrar
    sleep(5); //Tiempo de espera
    echo "<script>window.close();</script>"; //Cerrar ventana
    exit; //Exit
}
```

El problema es que con esto, no está imprimiendo el echo en este caso
Y mi idea es terminar imprimiendo una página completa de error, que proceda a cerrarse sola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tene en cuenta que `PHP` se ejecuta del lado del servidor, por lo que el `sleep` solo demora la carga de la página.

Si queres demorar el cierre de la ventana podes usar, por ejemplo, [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

> El método setTimeout() del mixin WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope establece un temporizador que ejecuta una función o una porción de código después de que transcurre un tiempo establecido.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
console.log('Espera 5 segundos...');
window.setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Listo!');
}, 1000 * 5);
```

---

Aplciado a tu código, podría quedar así:

```
echo "<script>window.setTimeout(function() {
   window.close();
}, 1000 * 5);</script>";
```

Comment: Como aplicaría esto, al else del php ¿? es decir, como detecto el momento del error para lanzarlo ?

Comment: @Excorpion, actualice mi respuesta. Espero que ahora te sirva.

Comment: Perfecto gracias !!!